# Is it possible to change the selected listview cell's height in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

When the user taps on an item I want the cell's height to change. 
When the user clicks out of that cell or to another cell I want the cell to go back to normal.

Comment: Have you tried setting your ListView's cellFactory to a factory which sets the returned ListCell's height (or font or other size-affecting attributes) based on whether it's selected?

Comment: I have not tried that yet. I will try that asap!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in CSS with the following in an external CSS file:

```
.list-cell:selected {
    -fx-cell-size: 36 ;
}
```

The default value is 24.